# How access System.Windows.Forms by Powershell on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: mono, powershell

I am developing a GUI with Powershell on Ubuntu (via Virtual Box) but I am not able to use System.Windows.Forms:

- I installed Mono-devel,
- I searched **apt-file search System.Windows.Forms.dll** retrieving 12
  different version,
- I copied the dll version 4.8 in the script
  directory,
- I run the command **Add-Type -AssemblyName
  System.Windows.Forms**
- The version 4.8 tells

```
Add-Type: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies cannot be loaded for execution. (0x80131058)
```

- The previous ones tells:

```
Add-Type could not load file or assembly ‘<Unknown>’ Index not found. (0x80131124)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint: https://github.com/mono/xwt